# How to protect password to display in HttpRequest in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am working in a project in which our clients wants to protect the LoginPage password during postback. At first I thought it is due to ViewState, so I added the following config under system.web

```
 <pages enableEventValidation="false" enableViewStateMac="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always"  controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
```

But even then, when I have a look into the HTTP headers, my password is visible very clearly (refer the link below)
http://www.sharexfiles.com/image/2015-02-17_153654.jpg[^]

Is there is anyway we can encrypt the password on the client side while the Login Request?

One possible solution could be modifying the websites to work under **https** but is there is any other way besides this

Comment: Using https is a requirement for login pages. You may avoid passwords by using OAuth with external login services like Facebook, Google etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you note https is the right answer to this situation.

There are likely some alternatives but the key consideration is reliability here. Https is reliable, well tested and constantly reviewed and improved, which allows you to be confident that the data is protected in transit.

With any custom solution you have to worry about all of the things that https does for you behind the scenes. In  particular, how do your client and server side actors share a common secret so that they can encrypt and decrypt data. Https does this for you.

Comment: HI Mike, What if the same problem occurs in https aswell. Our production project uses https and we can see the password in Post Request clearly (like the link that I have given). I am not sure what am I missing here